# The most efficient method for retrieving data from 15M+ records. Mysql + Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

let me get straight to the point.

An index has been assigned to created_at in this table. I need to fetch records from the last 7 days, and this operation needs to be efficient. I cannot use caching because the table receives a data entry every second. I need to retrieve the up-to-date information in the most efficient way with each query. What do you recommend?

Comment: How many records, on average, will there be in the last week? What will you be doing with the records? How frequently will the data be retrieved?

Comment: On average, 600,000 records are coming in for the last 7 days for now, and it seems to increase. group_id and created_at are indexed. I am providing statistics by counting these incoming records separately for each 7-day period.

Comment: Top of my head: 1 Don't use `*`, select columns that are needed only. 2 Use your query to get the first and last record, store the ID in PHP cache or session. 3 Query by batch, use add additional query of id less than last and more than first + limit and offset then push to an array or something. once you hit the last data, overwrite the first ID as the last ID + 1, remove last id, then repeat the process until you get your last record (assuming that there are hundreds of record added when you where doing your initial query batch.

Comment: since this is time consuming, use events.

Comment: In Amazon, they use heap priority queue data structure (may be min-heap priority queue) to handle very similar kind of problem, it helped to improve the performance by 20 times and sometimes even improved by 50 times. Give it a try.

Comment: Or try multi-level indexing.